# Action Bar Not Showing Menu Items

Tags: android, xml, model-view-controller, gradle, android-actionbar

(Please read before tagging as duplicated)

I know this question has been asked millions of times, but in my case **it doesn't have anything to do with the "ShowAsAction" property** on the item, I applied a personal theme to my actionbar, I have done this several times before, and never had any problems with the items on the menu at the actionbar. But in this particular project they have disappeared, and even if I set the default apptheme as Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar, still not getting any items shown.

**By the way I'm using Model–view–controller (MVC) Methodology on my design and development of this project (Please forgive my English is not my native language )**

Ill post all the code involved.

First my **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.prometheus.projectz.projectz" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".SubCategoryActivity"
        android:label="@string/subcategory_activity_title"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">

    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".ItemActivity"
        android:label="@string/items_activity_title"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">

    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

As i'm using the MVC model, the fragment is the one who inflates the menu (Done this several times with 100% success showing menu items on other projects)

**CategoryListFragment.java**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.List;

/**
* Created by JL on 24/04/2015.
*/
public class CategoryListFragment extends ListFragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,   Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_categories_list, container, false);


}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    List<CategoryEntity> categories =   CategoryFactory.getInstance().getCategories();
    loadCategories(categories);
}
private void loadCategories(List<CategoryEntity> categories) {

    CategoryItemAdapter categoryItemAdapter =  new  CategoryItemAdapter(getActivity(),categories);

    setListAdapter(categoryItemAdapter);
}
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    CategoryItemAdapter categoryItemAdapter= (CategoryItemAdapter)  l.getAdapter();
    CategoryEntity categoryEntity= (CategoryEntity)  categoryItemAdapter.getItem(position);


    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),SubCategoryActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(BundleKeys.KEY_CATEGORY_SUB_ID,          categoryEntity.getId_category());



   startActivity(intent);
}}
```

Now this is the "menu_main" that I'm trying to inflate:

**menu_main.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:icon="@drawable/search_icon"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
 />

<!-- I've tried changing the ShowAsAction to IfRoom so that's
not the problem-->
</menu>
```

**(The androidStudio's preview of this menu_main.xml doesn't show the items on the menu either)**

Now I have this on my Style resources: As you will see I've added support-library-compatibility to the items that needed it, (again, done this several times before)

**styles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="MyNewTheme">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
<color name="white">#ffff</color>
<color name="black">#0000</color>

<style name="MyNewTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarSize">50dp</item>

    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/white</item>

    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyNewActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabs</item>
    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyNewActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabs</item>



</style>

<style name="MyNewActionBar"   parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/action_bar_bg_1</item>
    <!--<item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/NoTitleText</item>-->
    <!--<item name="android:subtitleTextStyle">@style/NoTitleText</item>-->

    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/NewTitle</item>
    <item name="android:subtitleTextStyle">@style/NewTitle</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="background">@drawable/action_bar_bg_1</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/NewTitle</item>
    <item name="subtitleTextStyle">@style/NewTitle</item>

</style>

<style name="MyActionBarTabs"  parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabView">

    <item name="android:height">25dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/action_bar_tab_indicator_1</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="background">@drawable/action_bar_tab_indicator_1</item>
</style>

<style name="NoTitleText">
    <item name="android:textSize">0sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#00000000</item>
    <!-- Support library compatibility -->

</style>

<style name = "NewTitle" >
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffff</item>


</style>

<style name="BasicTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarSize">50dp</item>


</style>
</resources>
```

And finally this is my Gradle Script, this is where I think, the error must be, I personally work with an minSdkVersion 9, this way I cover most of the android OS from 2.3 to 5.

**build.gradle app**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.prometheus.projectz.projectz"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),   'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.0'
}
```

I've Worked 1 week on this project, and I really don't want to start over, because of this "BUG". 
PLEASE DON'T MARK THIS QUESTION AS DUPLICATED CAUSE IT'S NOT THE USUALLY ShowAsAction MISTAKE.

**I would really like to post some screenshots but I don't have the needed reputation yet.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing following function in your `Fragment` that indicates this `Fragment` has a menu.

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

Call this function in your `onCreateView` function.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setHasOptionsMenu(boolean)

Comment: Omg you're 100 % right! i feel so dumb! Thank you very much!